# Solving the problems that come with the dyadic function assertEquals(expected, actual)

Tags: functions

After years of cowboy coding, I decided to pick up a book on how to write good quality code. I'm reading Clean Code by Robert Cecil Martin. In chapter 3 (functions) there is a section on dyadic functions. Here is an excerpt from the book.

> Even obvious dyadic functions like `assertEquals(expected, actual)` are problematic. How many times have you put the actual where the expected should be? The two arguments have no natural ordering. The expected, actual ordering is a convention that requires practice to learn.

The author makes a compelling point. I work in machine learning and come across this all the time. For example, all of the metric functions in the sklearn library (probably the most used python library in the field) require you to be careful of the order of the inputs. As an example [sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html) takes as inputs `labels_true` and `labels_pred`. What this function does isn't too relevant, what is relevant is that if you switch the order of the inputs no error will be thrown. In fact switching the inputs is equivalent to using [another function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.completeness_score.html) in the library.

However the book does not go on to say a sensible fix for functions such as `assertEquals`. I cannot think of a fix for `assertEquals` or for functions I often come across like the one described above. What are good practices to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is good to be aware of a possible issue even when there's no fix – that way you can be vigilant when reading or writing such code. In this specific example, you just get used to the order of arguments after a while.

There are language level ways to prevent any confusion about parameter order: named arguments. This is unfortunately not supported in many languages with C-style syntax such as Java or C++. But in Python, every argument can be a named argument. Instead of calling a function `def foo(a, b)` as `foo(1, 2)`, we can do `foo(a=1, b=2)`. Many modern languages like C# have similar syntax. The Smalltalk language family has taken named arguments furthest: there aren't any positional args and *everything* is named. This can lead to code that reads very close to natural language.

A more practical alternative is to create APIs that simulate named arguments. These can be fluent APIs, or helper functions that create a natural flow. The `assertEquals(actual, expected)` name is confusing. Some alternatives I have seen:

- `assertThat(actual, is(equalTo(expected)))`: by wrapping some arguments in helper types, the wrapping functions effectively serve as parameter names. In the specific case of unit test assertions, this technique is used by [Hamcrest matchers](http://hamcrest.org/) to provide an extensible and composable assertion system. The disadvantage here is that you get a lot of nesting, and need to import lots of helper functions. This is my go-to technique in C++.
- `expect(actual).to.be(expected)`: a fluent API where you string function calls together. While this avoids extra nesting, this isn't very extensible. While I find that fluent APIs read very well, designing a good fluent API tends to take a lot of effort in my experience, because you need to implement additional classes for non-terminal states in the call chain. This effort only really pays off in the context of an autocompleting IDE that can suggest the next allowed method calls.

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods to avoid this problem. One that doesn't force you to change the method you call:

Rather than

```
assertEquals( 42, meaningOfLife() );
```

Use

```
expected = 42;
actual = meaningOfLife();
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

This forces the convention out into the open where it's easy to spot them getting switched. Sure it's not as easy to write but it is easy to read.

If you can change the method being called you can use the typing system to force usage that is easy to read.

```
assertThat( meaningOfLife(), is(42) );
```

Some languages let you avoid this because they have named parameters:

```
assertEquals( expected=42, actual=meaningOfLife() );
```

Others don't so you simulate them:

```
assertEquals().expected(42).actual( meaningOfLife() );
```

Whatever you do find a way that makes it obvious which is correct when read. Don't make me guess what the convention is.  Show it to me.